# Django how to validate requested URL against a choices field?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a choice field in one of my models in an app I am writing. It looks, for arguments sake, like:

```
MANUFACTURERS = (
    ('sk','skoda')
    ('vw','volkswagen')
)
class car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length='2', choices=MANUFACTURERS)
```

Now, I want to create a view to list all the cars by a manufacturer, I wired up the view to take a manufacturer argument as part of the URL, but the issue is then validating that this is indeed an accepted manufacturer abbreviation as per 'sk', or 'vw'.

Initially I went through a hacky process of importing the MANUFACTURERS constant, creating a list of the abbreviations, and checking that the given value exists in that list. Then iterating the MANUFACTURERS constant to get the full name.

```
for manufacturer in MANUFACTURERS:
    manufacturers.append(manufacturer[0])

if url_given_mfn in manufacturers:
    continue
else:
    raise Http404
```

etc. this is pretty inelegant - is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to make a dict out of the possible manufacturers, for example:

```
from mymodel import MANUFACTURERS
mdict = dict(MANUFACTURERS)


def myview(request, manufacturer):
    if not (manufacturer in mdict):
        raise Http404

    #--> do what you need to do
```

This way you are looking on the keys (the abrevation) and if you want to retrieve the value just do:

```
mdict[manufacturer]
```

You could do the dict in the model too and just import it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use Django form for that.

```
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect
from model import MANUFACTURERS
class manufacturerTypeForm(forms.Form):
    manufacturer = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, label= 'License Type', widget=RadioSelect(), choices=MANUFACTURERS)
```

so in view you have to just validate the form.If validate True just save it other wise show errot message.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the question I asked, I wanted to validate URL arguments to check them against an existing tuple of tuples for a form choices field. See the accepted answer.